# What is the cardinality ratio between class and interface?

Tags: java, oop, abap

What is the cardinality ratio between  class and interface?

1. Many to one
2. one to many
3. one to one
4. many to many

Comment: I did that. try finding out the answer anywhere on internet.

Comment: I attempted the quiz, but I don't know the answer. if u know pls give otherwise don't comment anything.

Comment: A class or interface can implement 0 or more interfaces.

Comment: I want to know if many to many is correct because one class can implement many interfaces and one interface can be implemented in many classes. so what is correct answer?

Comment: What is even the point in doing these quiz questions? What do those choices even mean? Sounds like a relational database... Do writing code _require_ this kind of knowledge? I think the answer is 4, btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why this question is voted down?

One interface can be implemented in none or multiple classes.

One class can implement none or multiple interfaces.

class <--|0...n|---|0...n|--> interface

So: Many to many

Comment: The question doesn't really make any sense. Classes and Interfaces are _things_ in an object oriented program model and the notion of _cardinality_ doesn't really have any meaning. It's asking the cardinality ratio of types to functions or forks to pies.